# jQuery set time out function

Tags: jquery

What is wrong in this function?

```
function getTuittingCookie() {
var tuitting_cookie = $.cookie("tuittingID");
$("#tuittingID").val(tuitting_cookie);
//alert(tuitting_cookie);
setTimeout(getTuittingCookie, 2000);
}
```

It should write the value every 2 seconds on the field:

```
<input id="tuittingID" style="display:none" value=""/>
```

But instead it does not write anything at all!

Can you help me please?

Comment: Side question: Why not use `<input id="tuittingID" type="hidden" value=""/>` instead of adding `style="display:none"`? Or as Ray Toal asked, are you intending to use a hidden `div`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you calling function `getTuittingCookie()` in your code . 
this code works for me see example at 
http://jsfiddle.net/Z9dcb/2/

```
function getTuittingCookie() {
var tuitting_cookie= Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
$("#tuittingID").val(tuitting_cookie);
//alert(tuitting_cookie);
setTimeout(getTuittingCookie, 2000);
}
getTuittingCookie();
```

and in place of using code

you could use

```
<input id="tuittingID" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are calling this function to begin with, everything looks fine.

`$.cookie()` will return `null` if a cookie is not found and assigning a null to the input's value using `.val(null);` is acceptable.

As for calling the function, you may want to do this on [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) as in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getTuittingCookie();
});
```

You may also want to consider using a hidden input `<input type="hidden" />` as it hides itself automatically without having to fuss with display:none.

Also, this is debatable, but it might be safer to call setTimeout() using a string expression rather than the function name itself to avoid null references.

```
setTimeout('getTuittingCookie()', 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write to a div, not an input, or else your input needs a type attribute and should not be display:none.

(Also, possibly stating the obvious, make sure the function is called and the cookie actually has content.)

Answer (score 0):

This code is working perfectly on my current brother.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        getTuittingCookie();
    }, 2000);
});
function getTuittingCookie() {
    var tuitting_cookie= Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
    $("#tuittingID").val(tuitting_cookie); 
}
```